# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to work on the U of a CRUD app. My edit form keeps saying things are undefined. It is saying that "name" under the "medicine name" label is undefined.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const EditMedicineForm = (props) => {
  const initialFormState = { id: null, name: "", directions: "" };
  const [medicine, setMedicine] = useState(props.currentMedicine);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMedicine(props.currentMedicine);
  }, [props]);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setMedicine({ ...medicine, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!medicine.name || !medicine.description) return;
        props.updateMedicine(medicine.id, medicine);
        setMedicine(initialFormState);
      }}
    >
      <label>medicine name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={medicine.name}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      <label>directions</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="directions"
        value={medicine.directions}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      <button>Update medicine</button>
      <button
        onClick={() => props.setEditing(false)}
        className="button muted-button"
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
export default EditMedicineForm;
```

Comment: I think the issue is here `setMedicine({ ...medicine, [name]: value });`. Try to remove `[]` around name like `setMedicine({ ...medicine, name: value });`. Are you trying to set `name` as a key or event name instead?

Answer (score 0):

Before that use a property of object please check the object first. The object has to have content. Like this:

```
if (medicine && (!medicine.name || !medicine.description)){
  return; 
}
```

Look for that at your code and change them.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of this bug could be in multiple places, but it's not too bad. It is a great exercise in debugging.

My guess is that `props.currentMedicine` is also undefined when the component is mounted.

To debug this, I'd start by checking right away to see if `medicine` is what you expect it to be when the component mounts:

```js
const EditMedicineForm = (props) => {
  const initialFormState = { id: null, name: "", directions: "" };
  const [medicine, setMedicine] = useState(props.currentMedicine);

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("The component just mounted! The value of medicine is:", medicine
  },[])

...
```

My guess is that `medicine` will be undefined. If that is indeed the case, I'd go here next:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const EditMedicineForm = (props) => {
  const initialFormState = { id: null, name: "", directions: "" };
  const [medicine, setMedicine] = useState(initialFormState); // CHANGE IS HERE

  useEffect(() => {
    setMedicine(props.currentMedicine);
  }, [props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("The value of medicine changed! It is now:", medicine) 
  }, [medicine]);

...
```

And, lastly, like another user suggested, I'd change my input's value to be:

```js
    <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={medicine?.name ?? ""}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      <label>directions</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="directions"
        value={medicine?.directions ?? ""}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
```

The `medicine?.name ?? ""` syntax is newish and it's called nullish coalescing, which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) - it is handy in situations like this.

Good luck and I hope this helps! U is the trickiest part of CRUD, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I think your useEffect is not good, because when props.currentMed undefined it will cause state become re-render .

And also you have props from the parent. So i try to make some simulation based on your scenario.

look at this simple solution based on your code:

[Codesandbox Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-haibt-8lqux?file=/src/App.js)